# how to cancel repeated gitlab pipelines and keep only the the las pipeline?

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

i'm using gitlab web hook to publish changes with content-full, for every change a pipeline get triggered,
A lot of pipelines run and waste resources, i'm looking for a solution to cancel unneeded pipeline

i found no option at gitlab so i made my own script :

```
check_redundancy:
  stage: check_redundancy
  image: public.ecr.aws/amazonlinux/amazonlinux:2
  before_script:
    - yum update -y
    - yum install -y unzip jq curl
  script:
    - >
      if true; then
        echo "Another pipeline is still running. Blocking older pipelines."
        echo $CI_API_V4_URL
        echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
        echo $CI_PROJECT_ID
        echo $CI_PIPELINE_IID
        CURRENT_PIPELINE_ID=$(($CI_PIPELINE_ID))
        PIPELINES=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/pipelines?ref=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME&status=running" | jq -r '.[].id // empty')
        echo $PIPELINES
        if [[ -n "$PIPELINES" ]]; then
          IFS=$'\n'
          for PIPELINE_ID in $(echo "$PIPELINES" | tac); do
            PIPELINE_IDD=$(($PIPELINE_ID))
            if [ "$PIPELINE_IDD" -lt "$CURRENT_PIPELINE_ID" ]; then
              echo "Cancelling pipeline with ID: $PIPELINE_ID"
              curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/pipelines/$PIPELINE_ID/cancel" &
            fi
          done
          wait
        else
          echo "No previous running pipelines found."
        fi
      fi
  rules:
    - when: always
```

problem is it's a bit slow, is there a better solution or a better enhancement for speed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Auto-Cancel Redundant Pipelines setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#auto-cancel-redundant-pipelines)

> You can set pending or running pipelines to cancel automatically when a pipeline for new changes runs on the same branch. You can enable this in the project settings:
>
> On the left sidebar, at the top, select **Search GitLab** to find your project.
>
> 1. Select **Settings > CI/CD**.
> 2. Expand **General Pipelines**.
> 3. Select the **Auto-cancel redundant pipelines** checkbox.
> 4. Select **Save changes**.

Comment: this option doesn't work, i don't know why